# Use awk to print fields separated by /

Tags: awk

I have this list of download links.

```
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18289288/114326c538e72a0cf23b9bc82aae1a36/de/Babylon_5_20.03.31_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/267994/29709747
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18287021/60f414e4589608f806873c4c3df79b87/de/Babylon_5_20.03.30_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/512242/29699567
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18280561/f1b399cf3283b19d7bdcac959dea37e6/de/Babylon_5_20.03.27_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/791489/29671092
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18258229/e4d94ac7ea38a8f0551a93d2c3703219/de/Babylon_5_20.03.26_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/787046/29660809
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18256176/835ce99116e11ee417fb12d41e44867d/de/Babylon_5_20.03.25_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/261645/29650516
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18254120/e4a69bcc66a0491c949f5f43736f3fb9/de/Babylon_5_20.03.24_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/428464/29640134
https://download6.onlinetvrecorder.com/download/2540675/flatrate/18251876/82863dcdb412cd44c49b9956959b8685/de/Babylon_5_20.03.23_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi/479411/29629751
```

It turns out the download daemon used the last entry as file name.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 593984618 Mar 23 14:56  29629751
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 632598628 Mar 24 14:57  29640134
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 535594310 Mar 25 14:55  29650516
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 537082534 Mar 26 14:55  29660809
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 529020006 Mar 27 14:55  29671092
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 560333670 Mar 30 15:05  29699567
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gottsch gottsch 534740104 Mar 31 14:56  29709747
```

I now want to rename the files to something more meaningful.

Using awk :

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print "mv ",$12,$10}' wunschliste.txt.fertig
```

I am expecting something like :

```
mv 29709747 Babylon_5_20.03.31_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
```

However (unexpectedly) I get:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print "mv ",$12,$10}' wunschliste.txt.fertig
 Babylon_5_20.03.31_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.30_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.27_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.26_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.25_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.24_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
 Babylon_5_20.03.23_19-10_tele5_65_TVOON_DE.mpg.HQ.avi
```

Well, where is my 'mv' ? Where is the first argument?

Edit. there was an ask for this cmd:

```
head -1 wunschliste.txt.fertig | od -c
0000000   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   d   o   w   n   l   o   a   d
0000020   8   .   o   n   l   i   n   e   t   v   r   e   c   o   r   d
0000040   e   r   .   c   o   m   /   d   o   w   n   l   o   a   d   /
0000060   2   5   4   0   6   7   5   /   f   l   a   t   r   a   t   e
0000100   /   1   8   3   9   6   9   8   2   /   e   e   5   5   0   3
0000120   a   6   f   d   3   f   9   f   2   5   8   c   4   c   1   4
0000140   2   b   f   a   a   4   4   c   9   f   /   d   e   /   B   a
0000160   b   y   l   o   n   _   5   _   2   0   .   0   4   .   2   4
0000200   _   1   9   -   1   0   _   t   e   l   e   5   _   6   5   _
0000220   T   V   O   O   N   _   D   E   .   m   p   g   .   H   Q   .
0000240   c   u   t   .   m   p   4   /   1   1   2   9   7   0   /   2
0000260   9   9   5   8   8   4   8  \r  \n
0000271
```

Comment: Try this first: `dos2unix wunschliste.txt.fertig`.

Comment: mostly likely this is the issue [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Can you please share output of  `head  -1 wunschliste.txt.fertig |  od -c`

Comment: Not the issue but make it `print "mv -- \047" $12 "\047 \047" $10 "\047"` so the `mv` will succeed no matter what characters are in your strings. The way you have it written above to generate a mv command without quotes around the file names would cause the mv to fail given various characters in your strings, contents of the directory you run it from, environment settings, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to it this when this can be simply done:

while read v_read
do
 v_curr_file_nm=`echo $v_read | awk -F "/" '{print $12}'`
 v_updt_file_nm=`echo $v_read | awk -F "/" '{print $10}'`
 mv ${v_curr_file_nm} ${v_updt_file_nm}
done < wunschliste.txt.fertig